# How to enable caching of model data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, model

How do I enable caching across requests/actions?

My stack:

- Rails 4.2.7
- Postgres 9.5

I notice the following in my Rails logs

```
  Country Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."iso" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["iso", "US"]]
  State Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "states".* FROM "states" WHERE "states"."iso" = $1 AND "states"."country_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["iso", "OH"], ["country_id", 233]]
  Country Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."iso" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["iso", "US"]]
  State Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "states".* FROM "states" WHERE "states"."iso" = $1 AND "states"."country_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["iso", "OH"], ["country_id", 233]]
  Country Load (3.6ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."iso" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["iso", "US"]]
  State Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "states".* FROM "states" WHERE "states"."iso" = $1 AND "states"."country_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["iso", "OH"], ["country_id", 233]]
```

Note that the same queries are being run multiple times against my database in rapid succession.  Is there some way I can indicate to Rails that certain tables/models are very unlikely to change, and so certain lookups can be cached on the app server?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there some way I can indicate to Rails that certain tables/models
>   are very unlikely to change, and so certain lookups can be cached on
>   the app server?

Absolutely, ***model caching*** seems to be a perfect fit here.

[Here's the article](https://www.sitepoint.com/speed-things-up-by-learning-about-caching-in-rails/) which will give you a good overview of setting up different types of caching.

Also, check out [official guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) on caching.

Basically, you want to look into model caching.

You can write an extention and use it in models, which are to be cached:

```
module ModelCachingExtention
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    class << self
      # The first time you call Model.all_cached it will cache the collection,
      # each consequent call will not fire the DB query
      def all_cached
        Rails.cache.fetch(['cached_', name.underscore.to_s, 's']) { all.load }
      end
    end

    after_commit :clear_cache

    private

    # Making sure, that data is in consistent state by removing the cache
    # everytime, the table is touched (eg some record is edited/created/destroyed etc).
    def clear_cache
      Rails.cache.delete(['cached_', self.class.name.underscore.to_s, 's'])
    end
  end
end
```

Then use it in model:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ModelCachingExtention
end
```

Now, when using `Country.all_cached` you will have the cached collection returned with zero db queries (once it is cached).

Comment: So I'm understanding you correctly, the only way to cache queries is to write a new method (e.g. "find_by_id_cached") and then change my inovocations across my application to use the new query.  Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @Dave as I said, there are always few ways to do things. This is one of the ways to minimize db queries. You can check out the links I've provided + [this nice railscast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8ausBZTrxU). But with described approach - indeed, you'll have to change your invocations across app. Also some caching is already done by Rails by default.

Comment: The link you posted -- the sitepoint.com site, does not deal with query caching with the one exception of what you have given in your answer (it talks more about page caching).  I will check out your Railscast.

Comment: @Dave after all, this all is data caching and yea, the link is more about types of caching, probably the wording I used while providing it is not accurate. As to railscast - I wish it was mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Within a single request queries are already cached by Rails. You will see it within your logfile with the prefix `CACHE`. Some operations, like inserting a new record within your request leads to a `clear_query_cache` and all cache entries are gone.

If you want that your query cache has a longer life time, you have to do it on your own. You can use Rails caching features for this:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("countries iso: #{iso}", expires_in: 1.hour) do
  Country.where(iso: iso).all
end
```

You can also use memcache. With memcache you can share cached data between multiple servers.
You have to set it up within your specific environment config.

`config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, "cache-1.example.com", "cache-2.example.com"`

Comment: I see no lines anywhere in my logfiles that contain the word "CACHE".  I am running in development mode on my Mac El Capitan machine so perhaps there is anotehr settings I need to enable but I don't think caching is being used otherwise why would the queries be executed against the database.

Comment: This cache is only within a controller action enabled. Try to call within an action multiple times `Country.all; Country.all`  then you should see first `Country Load` and after this `CACHE`. If not check your setting for `config.cache_store`.

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect taht I'm interested in caching beyond a single action.  My question refers to more broadly caching read-only data during the life of the application.

Comment: Then take a look at the awnser of @Andrey Deineko and the Rails caching guide. `@data = Rails.cache.fetch("your perfect cache key", expires_in: 1.hour) { fetch_what_ever_you_want() }` is the key. Within development mode you have to enable this kind of cache.